# wierd location, distance output for maps using gps

Tags: android, gps, location, distance

after some time where i run my app, the distance remains 0 which is correct since i am not moving, but after 20-30 min in between it gain to 8-18 meters, i forgot. even more later, it grow to hundred. over time the marker gets more dispersed.
how can i pinpoint a location and if i never move, stop changing? 
if i move, from my room to my living room, should be 4-7meters about i think, the distance never increase.
for those who done similar stuff before, does the blue dot and red marker goes together. my blue dot is not correct most of the time

i really do not know where i can improve my codes or what is the cause of the output..

[image]

My MainActivity File

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener{

protected LocationManager locationManager;
private GoogleMap googleMap;
Button btnStartMove,btnPause,btnResume,btnStop;
static double n=0;
Long s1,r1;
double dis=0.0;
Thread t1;
EditText userNumberInput;
boolean bool=false;
int count=0;

double speed = 1.6;
double lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2,lat3,lon3,lat4,lon4;
double dist = 0;
TextView distanceText;
float[] result;
private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES =1; // in Meters
private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 4000; //in milliseconds
boolean startDistance = false;
boolean startButtonClicked = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
    if(isGooglePlay())
    {
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }
    distanceText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Distance);
    btnStartMove=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Start);//start moving

    //prepare distance...........
    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");  
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    btnStartMove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");  
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            Location location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            lat3 = location.getLatitude();
            lon3 = location.getLongitude();
            startButtonClicked=true;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                      "start is true",    
                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    });

    if(location!= null)
    {
        //Display current location in Toast
        String message = String.format(
                "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
        );
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //Display current location in textview  
        //latitude.setText("Current Latitude: " + String.valueOf(location.getLatitude())); 
        //longitude.setText("Current Longitude: " + String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
    }
    else if(location == null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Location is null",    
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    if(googleMap == null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Getting map",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        googleMap =((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.displayMap)).getMap();

        if(googleMap != null)
        {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }

}

private void setUpMap() 
{
    //Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    //Get locationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    //LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    //Get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    if(provider == null)
    {
        onProviderDisabled(provider);
    }
    //set map type
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    //Get current location
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if(myLocation != null)
    {
        onLocationChanged(myLocation);
    }       
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);
}

private boolean isGooglePlay() 
{
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
    {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Google Play Services is available",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return(true);
    }
    else
    {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 10).show();

    }
    return (false);

 }

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location myLocation) {
    System.out.println("speed " + myLocation.getSpeed());


//      if(myLocation.getSpeed() > speed)//return 0 in actual
//      {
        //show location on map.................
        //Get latitude of the current location
        double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
        //Get longitude of the current location
        double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
        //Create a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        //Show the current location in Google Map
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        //Zoom in the Google Map
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here!"));

        //show distance............................

        if(startDistance == true)
        {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                      "Location has changed",    
                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(myLocation != null)
                {
                    //latitude.setText("Current Latitude: " + String.valueOf(loc2.getLatitude())); 
                    //longitude.setText("Current Longitude: " + String.valueOf(loc2.getLongitude()));
                    float[] results = new float[1]; 
                    Location.distanceBetween(lat3, lon3, myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude(), results);
                    System.out.println("Distance is: " + results[0]);               

                    dist += results[0];            
                    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); // adjust this as appropriate
                if(count==1)
                {
                    distanceText.setText(df.format(dist) + "meters");
                }
                    lat3=myLocation.getLatitude();
                    lon3=myLocation.getLongitude();
                    count=1;
              }

        }
        if(startButtonClicked == true)
        {
            startDistance=true;
        }

    //}


}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Provider status changed",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
}}
```

i tried changing the min time and distance to all sorts of data and it remains the same. i never really move my phone most of the time in the above output. one time i move out for short while but distance did not increase. for those that done similar running app, which part do i need to change..i can't spot where is something wrong..

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, as long as you're not using GPS your position can be very inaccurate since it's only using the internet and your mobile network information. The accuracy of such measurements can vary greatly, from 10-20 meters up to 2000-3000+ meters. That said, even staying on the same network and in the same location sometimes the accuracy changes and with it your position changes. So you might see your accurate location now, in a few minutes you might be a kilometer away from where you really are on the map. And in case you're using GPS, keep in mind that GPS isn't always available (ie. when you're indoors) and takes some time to start up.

you might want to use only GPS which would make your app unusable in case you're not outside, or you could come up with an algorithm to check if you really are at the new location (use the locations accuracy, time since last location update, or something like that).

Comment: i am using gps. i check that my gps is emabled at all time. sometimes it stays at my location. even when i'm indoors, when gps is enabled it may have some inaccuracies? the thing is, i wanted it to calculate my distance even when i walk around a big room, for presenting purposes, but it seems to either wait a while to calculated when i not moving or even when i move it did not show any changes. so there is no way to make it more accurate indoors?thanks